# change cache to Reids and the exception:NOAUTH Authentication required occurred

Tags: redis

My magento version is 2.2.6，It is strange,becuase I can see the data in Reids,that means can write to Reids,and the system knows the password,Why did I mention this error when I visited the website?

[image]

[image]

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'redis',
    [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '6379',
        'password' => '123456',

'cache' =>
    array (
        'frontend' =>
            array (
                'default' =>
                    array (
                        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                        'backend_options' =>
                            array (
                                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                                'port' => '6379',
                                'persistent' => '',
                                'database' => 1,
                                'password' => '123456',
'page_cache' =>
    array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' =>
            array (
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'password'=>'123456',
```